# Good books on integrals

Tags: integration, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm a math student at the sixth semester and I've had my courses in calculus and complex analysis. I'm able to solve integrals with the usual techniques. However, whenever I am confronted with a difficult integral or with a manipulation of integrals, I usually don't know what to do.

So I'd like to read an advanced book on integrals, on how to solve them, how to manipulate them, how to estimate them. Does anyone have a good suggestion on such a kind of book?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you mostly work with definite integrals (much more tricky and interesting bunch) this book will be great: [Inside Interesting Integrals...](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493912766)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book named [Irresistible Integrals by George Boros and Victor Moll](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511617041) seems to fit to your purpose. I found it several years before after having hard time trying to prove some integral formula in the integral table of G&R and it really was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

*A Garden of Integrals* is quite nice.

Comment: This answer may be valid, but a bit more background or explanation about the book may be helpful.